# Django заполнить таблицу DB при миграции

Tags: django

Подскажите как заполнить таблицу базы данных при миграции. Есть модель подписок, у нее названия константы, хотелось бы при миграции чтобы эта таблица сразу заполнилась данными из списка. Подскажите как правильно реализовать. Заранее всем спасибо. Модель ниже:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = (
    ('Free', 'free'),
    ('Start', 'start'),
    ('Optimal', 'opt'),
    ('Freedom', 'frdom')
)
membership_type = models.CharField(choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES, default='Free', max_length=30)
price = models.IntegerField(default=10)
description = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True, default='')
period = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='')
```

Comment: data migration https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два пути:

1. Через изменение файла миграции - сложно и в целом плохо скажется на поддержке кода. Почитайте о файлах миграции.
2. Через заполнение базы начальными данными из предварительно подготовленных файлов fixtures. Это файлы в формате JSON в которых вы описываете чем заполнить вашу модель. Нужно создать папку fixtures в директории приложения. Подробней почитайте тут https://djbook.ru/rel1.7/howto/initial-data.html

На сколько я понимаю django не предоставляет возможности заполнять модель данными из model.py. Что логично в рамках идеологии MVC.